# iOS - Determine User's country without using CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, location, ip-address, cllocationmanager, nslocale

I don't need precise location data, and I don't want the user to see the "This App wants to determine your location" Alert. I just need to determine the user's country, assuming they have an internet connection via network or wi-fi.

What is the best way to do this? Is there some way to use their IP?

This would only work if they had a carrier:

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
```

And `NSLocale` is not reliable in that the user can change it in their device settings. Can't use the device's language setting for the same reason. I need the country based on where they are physically located.

Comment: Since a user might be in airplane mode or not connected to a network, or the user could be using a proxy, there is no guarantee you can get accurate info from the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the user's IP address and use a geolocation database to guess their location based on that as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_location . If you are just concerned with region, you can probably find some data at regional internet registries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry) websites to help you, since they control all the IP addresses for a particular region.

Comment: How would you get around this issue - If I'm on my home wi-fi my IP is 192.168.x.x, and if I'm on my cell network my IP is 10.174.x.x?

Comment: You're right, you'll just be getting garbage for your ip address -- this would only work if you were a website or something. I would try some of the answers here to get the address of the router itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113580/objective-c-how-to-fetch-the-router-address?lq=1 .

Comment: Your local IP address (eg: 192.168.x.x) is different than your external IP address. So if you're going to use an IP address to get user's location, you need to get his external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this url [How can whatsapp know country code upon first run on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577144/how-can-whatsapp-know-country-code-upon-first-run-on-iphone).. 
Hope this question and the question in the url i have given works for you